# What is causing this segmentation fault while using SSE instructions?

Tags: gcc, assembly, segmentation-fault, inline-assembly

This problem is driving me a bit crazy. The code seems to be [segmentation faulting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) for no good reason:

```
#define MULT_FLOAT4(X, Y) ({ \
    asm volatile ( \
        "movups (%0), %%xmm0\n\t" \
        "mulps (%1), %%xmm0\n\t" \
        "movups %%xmm0, (%1)" \
        :: "r" (X), "r" (Y)); })

int main(void)
{
    int before;
    float a[4] = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
    float b[4] = { 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 };

    /* Segmentation faults if I uncomment this line below, otherwise works fine. Why?? */
    int after;

    MULT_FLOAT4(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that so long as I have defined both the 'before' and 'after' variables it segmentation faults. If I just have 'before' or just have 'after' then it works fine.

I'm on Ubuntu Hardy (8.04), [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) version 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4). Linux kernel: 2.6.24-16-generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the address of a and b.  I suspect you'll find that they must be aligned to a 16 byte boundary in order to avoid a segfault.  Adding `__ attribute __((aligned(16)))` after their declarations should do the trick.

That's two underscores on each side of attribute and connected to it, BTW.

Comment: hmmm i thought movups was for unaligned data - and movaps was for aligned? :)

Comment: it works! thanks! ...though im still confused as to why it's segfaulting when im using movups which specifically is for unaligned data?

Comment: It's the mulps trying to access b.  gdb should be able to show which instruction triggers the segfault.